# Class with string literal constructor won't work with const reference initialization

Tags: c++

I tested the following code with g++ *(Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04)* and *(MinGW.org GCC-8.2.0-3)*.

```cpp
struct test {
    template <unsigned long int N>
    test(const char(&)[N]){
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }
};

void func(const test&){}

int main(){
    test val1 = "test";
    const test val2 = "test";
    /* const test &ref1 = "test"; */
    const test &ref2 = (test)"test";
    func("test");
}
```

Output with **ref1** commented :

```
g++ test.cpp -o test.exe && test.exe
test::test(const char (&)[N]) [with long unsigned int N = 5]
test::test(const char (&)[N]) [with long unsigned int N = 5]
test::test(const char (&)[N]) [with long unsigned int N = 5]
test::test(const char (&)[N]) [with long unsigned int N = 5]
```

Output with **ref1** uncommented :

```
g++ test.cpp -o test.exe && test.exe
test.cpp: In function 'int main()':
test.cpp:15:24: error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'const test&' from expression of type 'const char*'
     const test &ref1 = "test";
                        ^~~~~~
```

I thought I know and master const references in c++ but it is the first time I encountered this situation and I did not find the explanation neither the solution yet. My questions are :

1. What is the difference between initialization of const value **val2**, const reference **ref1** and parameter of **func** ?
2. Why initialization of const reference **ref1** trigger the error above ?
3. Why explicit call of the constructor does not trigger the error for **ref2** ?
4. Is it standard or is there any difference with other compilers ?
5. Is there a solution for **ref1** ?

Thank you.

Comment: Funny enough, gcc rejects it, clang accepts it: https://godbolt.org/z/Xlb4Kg

Comment: [MSVS also compiles the code](https://godbolt.org/z/K8XNtX). Me thinks this is a gcc bug.  I'll let other parse through the standard on this though as initialization rules are quite complex and messy.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the commented line is correct. Looks like a GCC bug.

Comment: A tip on writing sample code for this site: don't show all the tests that worked. Show the one that failed. That way people don't have to read through all of the non-errors to figure out what the problem is. So `main` should look like this: `int main() { const test &ref1 = "test"; }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your comments. Indeed it looks like a GCC bug.

Waiting for this being resolved, I finally found the following workaround in order to compile with GCC. I added a contructor overload which accept also only string literals but with a warning. Thus I can identify which line causes problem in my code.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct test {
    template <unsigned long int N>
    test(const char(&)[N]){
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }

    //Compatibility with GCC
    [[gnu::deprecated("[WARNING] Don't use string literals on const reference !")]]
    test(char *&&ptr){
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }
};

void func(const test&){}

int main(){
    test val1 = "test";
    const test val2 = "test";
    const test &ref1 = "test";
    const test &ref2 = (test)"test";
    func("test");
}
```

Output with GCC :

```
g++ test.cpp -o test.exe && test.exe
test.cpp: In function 'int main()':
test.cpp:21:24: warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
     const test &ref1 = "test";
                        ^~~~~~
test.cpp:21:24: warning: 'test::test(char*&&)' is deprecated: [WARNING] Don't use string literals on const reference ! [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
test.cpp:11:5: note: declared here
     test(char *&&ptr){
     ^~~~
test::test(const char (&)[N]) [with long unsigned int N = 5]
test::test(const char (&)[N]) [with long unsigned int N = 5]
test::test(char*&&)
test::test(const char (&)[N]) [with long unsigned int N = 5]
test::test(const char (&)[N]) [with long unsigned int N = 5]
```

Output with clang :

```
clang++ test.cpp -o test.out && ./test.out
test::test(const char (&)[N]) [N = 5]
test::test(const char (&)[N]) [N = 5]
test::test(const char (&)[N]) [N = 5]
test::test(const char (&)[N]) [N = 5]
test::test(const char (&)[N]) [N = 5]
```